# Google Nexus 4 for Android Development?

Tags: android

I want to buy a phone for android development and testing. I know that Galaxy Nexus has good reputation among developers what about new nexus 4?

In Nexus 4 my minimum OS version will be 4.1.2 or 4.2. If I wanted to test previous versions would I need another phone? 

If I upgraded nexus 4 to next OS verson (for example android 5.0) I would be able to downgrade it to 4.1. How complicated is to flash ROM on Nexus series?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that SO is not a recommendation site. You may have more luck on AndroidEnthusiasts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, using the most recent version of Android for development is the way to go. (E.g.: Pre-honeycomb versions stored raster data of images/bitmaps in native memory, thus the Memory Analyzer Tool, when you searched for memory leaks not showed the actual size of a bitmap leaked, just a few hundreds of bytes.)

On the other hand, vendors are customizing their phones, they have different drivers for example the camera. So testing only on one phone, in some situations might not be enough... I'd advise to have an older phone (with low available memory, pre-honeycomb os), and a newer one...

You should integrate ACRA, or other crash reporter tool, that enables you to track your product out in the wild. Bugsense or similar solutions provide you a nice Web interface, where you can see the different Exceptions that occured in your code for users...

If you don't have access to an actual phone, TestDroid from bitbar.com can provide a solution, as they have a cloud of different android phones (>100) where you can execute your test cases...

As for downgrading, I don't know if that is supported...

Answer (score 0):

But the latest phone you can get. Longevity is better that way. You can test for other phones on the in-built emulators.

Here are some links to help you out:

https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html

https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTesting/article.html